# How to authenticate to AWS using federation to launch ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm new to AWS. My company uses AD federation to login to the AWS management console. I am trying to launch an ec2 instance via Ansible 2.7.5, but I think I need to authenticate to AWS using the sts_session_token module?

ansible 2.7.5
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['~/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.7.5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.2 (default, Jan 13 2019, 12:50:15) [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]

My thinking is from this link here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-xbHX-_zfAhWGiOAKHUslBdAQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.slideshare.net%2FAmazonWebServices%2Fdelegating-access-to-your-aws-environment&psig=AOvVaw2fyLa59UGpxplzXgLCyDqB&ust=1548094527815558

My thinking is from this link here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-xbHX-_zfAhWGiOAKHUslBdAQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.slideshare.net%2FAmazonWebServices%2Fdelegating-access-to-your-aws-environment&psig=AOvVaw2fyLa59UGpxplzXgLCyDqB&ust=1548094527815558

For python I have boto, boto3, and botocore installed.

I have a ~/.aws/ directory with credentials and config

Credentials

[default]

aws_access_key_id =

aws_secret_access_key =

Config

[default]

region=us-east-1

output=json

Ansible Playbook

```
 ---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: False
   tasks:

      - name: Get Session Token Credentials from STS
        sts_session_token:
         duration_seconds: 3600
        register: session_credentials

      - debug:
         var: session_credentials

      - name: Assume Role AWS
        sts_assume_role:
         role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::<id+role>"
         role_session_name: "session role name"
        register: assumed_role

      - debug:
         var: assumed_role`
```

Errored Results:

The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1548008584.240192-70823728355706/AnsiballZ_sts_session_token.py", line 113, in 
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1548008584.240192-70823728355706/AnsiballZ_sts_session_token.py", line 105, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1548008584.240192-70823728355706/AnsiballZ_sts_session_token.py", line 48, in invoke_module
    imp.load_module('**main**', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
  File "/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/**main**.py", line 155, in 
  File "/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/**main**.py", line 151, in main
  File "/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/**main**.py", line 124, in get_session_token
  File "/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/ansible_sts_session_token_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2369, in fail_json
  File "/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/ansible_sts_session_token_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2341, in _return_formatted
  File "/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/ansible_sts_session_token_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 522, in remove_values
  File "/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/ansible_sts_session_token_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 505, in _remove_values_conditions
TypeError: Value of unknown type: , An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1548008584.240192-70823728355706/AnsiballZ_sts_session_token.py\", line 113, in \n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1548008584.240192-70823728355706/AnsiballZ_sts_session_token.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1548008584.240192-70823728355706/AnsiballZ_sts_session_token.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\n    imp.load_module('**main**', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\n  File \"/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/**main**.py\", line 155, in \n  File \"/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/**main**.py\", line 151, in main\n  File \"/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/**main**.py\", line 124, in get_session_token\n  File \"/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/ansible_sts_session_token_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 2369, in fail_json\n  File \"/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/ansible_sts_session_token_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 2341, in _return_formatted\n  File \"/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/ansible_sts_session_token_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line522, in remove_values\n  File \"/var/folders/gn/2zrt_ymj2_qf1dqysz6rgk99ymbz39/T/ansible_sts_session_token_payload_6Rj3ys/ansible_sts_session_token_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 505, in _remove_values_conditions\nTypeError: Value of unknown type: , An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: The security token included in the request isinvalid.\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to try with [EC2 module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_module.html) and install boto and [configure](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) it. You may find the sample playbook [here](https://github.com/codefreaker/ansible-aws-wordpress). This is the simplest way to do this. But storing credentials in EC2 instances(your ansible box) is not a recommended way and advise to use an AWS role.

Comment: Boto appears to use aws_secret_key, due to federation, I don't have the ability to generate these for a particular user in AWS.